# Remove words from comments in vim autocompletion

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, autocompletion

I have looked for similar questions but I was quite surprised to not find anything similar... either I am the first person on this planet to have this issue, or I have searched using bad keywords.

Anyway, I use vim's autocomplete function (`<C-n>`) a lot to write python scripts. However, in the list of suggested words, there are also words that I previously used in comments, for example:

[image: huge list of suggestion]

here, many words suggested by vim (e.g. polymorphism, please, possible, etc.) are part of comments. In this way, the list of suggestions becomes very quickly long and confusing. I would like to remove from the list of suggestions words that were previusly typed in comments, and only keep the other ones. How can I achieve this?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that unless you write your own completion function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @romainl. So how do people do? They just accept a kilometric list of suggested words?

Comment: I don't know what *people* do, but *I* never trigger completion after one letter, precisely because it would be a largely irrelevant mess. Two or three characters is a good rule of thumb, IMO. I am not sure what, exactly, you wanted to complete in your screenshot (you didn't mention it) but pressing `<C-n>` would give you 3 suggestions after `ph`, 10 after `pr`, 2 after `po`, etc. which is a lot more manageable than the potential 26*x suggestions you would get after `p`. Note that starting completion after a few letter is a very common UX pattern for the same reason.

Comment: Alternatively, you could switch to a smarter completion method that only suggests the members of the specific object you are interested in, but that's a matter for a Google session, not for this question/comment thread.